# Python pandas adding a column of one and two when changing the sign taking into account the same sign

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that looks something like this:

| Ema1 | Ema2 | Delta_ema | Comulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | -1 | -1 |
| 9 | 15 | -6 | -7 |
| 29 | 3 | 26 | 19 |
| 8 | 2 | 6 | 22 |
| 5 | 20 | -15 | 7 |
| 2 | 21 | -19 | -12 |
| 8 | 22 | -14 | -26 |
| 30 | 2 | 28 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 | 1 | 3 |

I would like to add to this csv a column with the value of one when changing the sign in the Cumulative column, taking into account the same sign, so that it would turn out something like this csv

| Ema1 | Ema2 | Delta_ema | Comulative | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | -1 | -1 | 0 |
| 9 | 15 | -6 | -7 | 0 |
| 29 | 3 | 26 | 19 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | 6 | 22 | 0 |
| 5 | 20 | -15 | 7 | 0 |
| 2 | 21 | -19 | -12 | -1 |
| 8 | 22 | -14 | -26 | 0 |
| 30 | 2 | 28 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 0 |

In my original csv file, the Comulative column usually does not change the sign from about 100 to 500 lines here , for clarity , it changes so often !

Can you tell me how to do it better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column like this:

```
df['answer'] = np.diff(np.sign(df.Comulative), prepend=df.Comulative.to_numpy()[0]) // 2
```

and then save back to csv.

[`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html?highlight=diff#numpy.diff) return the difference between two elements (rows). For the first element, the difference in `NaN`, so we prepend the first element to automatically get a differenc of `0`.